# In jquery 1.4 and 1.3, loading just the framework definition causes an error, why?

Tags: jquery, exception

Whenever I load ONLY the 1.3 or 1.4 library on an html page im developing on my desktop I get an error that says "**setting a property that only has a getter**"

I dont have any additonal code, this is coming straight from the jquery.min.js file

I also get a bazillion warnings in Firebug.

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

I can't determine why this is happening

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is that the only JavaScript file you are loading?

Comment: yes. and now when i load jquery 1.4 unminified i get a jQuery not defined error =/

Comment: Show us how you're including the file, that's probably where the problem lies.

Comment: can you show us the simplest html that causes this issue?

Comment: Does this work? `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`  That test will eliminate a bad jQuery file as the issue.  From what I've seen of this before though, it's sometimes related to some bad CSS, just a very misrepresented error in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try a simple function call to see if the base is even loaded.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      alert("howdy"); 
    });
```

alternative, find out if it is loaded (better)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') 
{ 
    alert('not loaded');
} 
</script>
```

Third alternative, since I cannot know for sure if you have the library at the path you SAY it is within:
change to :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: FOR THE SHORT NUTS OUT THERE: (no typeof needed :)

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
    if (!window.jQuery) 
    { 
        alert('not loaded');
    } 
    </script>
```

Comment: Ahem, the short nuts would use `if(!this.$)` thank you very much!

Comment: LOL just KNEW one would chime in here with an alternative :)  Keep it up Nick!

Comment: I'd use `if(!$)` if the undefined rules would let me :)